# Django - How to add data from AJAX button into html, so it updates everytime button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, django

currently, I've got an ajax like button set up. The console shows that the like count is toggling when I press the button, but how do I actually retrieve the 'like_count' variable to put into my HTML. My button code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function toggleLike(){
        $.ajax({
          url: "{% url 'photo_blog-post_like_api' post.id %}",
          data: {like_count: 'like_count', 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
          }
          });
      };

</script>
```

and the html for the button is:

```
<input type="button" onclick="toggleLike()" value="Like"/>
```

and the code for my view is:

```
    class LikePostAPI(APIView):
        authentication_classes = (authentication.SessionAuthentication,)
        permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, slug=None, format=None, pk=None):
        obj = get_object_or_404(Post, id=pk)
        user = self.request.user
        updated = False
        liked = False
        if user.is_authenticated:
            if user in obj.likes.all():
                liked = False
                obj.likes.remove(user)
                like_count = obj.likes.count()
            else:
                liked = True
                obj.likes.add(user)
                like_count = obj.likes.count()
            updated = True
        data = {
            "updated": updated,
            "liked": liked,
            "like_count": like_count
        }
        return Response(data)
```

Comment: Totally unrelated but you MUST NOT use a GET request to update the server's state - GET requests MUST be idempotent. Use POST instead.

Comment: Also, this `if user in obj.likes.all()` is terribly innefficient. You want `if obj.likes.filter(user_id=user.id).exists()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add this line to the success function of the ajax request:

```
$("#likeCount").html(data.like_count);
```

where likeCount is the Id ot the html tag where you want to put the value, like:

```
<div id="likeCount"></div>
```

Comment: Oh, that was incredibly easy. When the page is first loaded, there is no count, until the button is clicked. Is there a way to get it displayed immediately when the page loads?   edit -- I added the id to a link with the initial like_count, which gets replaced when the button is clicked. Thanks!

Comment: just run the toggleLike function on document ready:
$( document ).ready(function() {
  toggleLike();
});